# Updating repositories in Azure Devops with PAT token through Python

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am trying to disable a repo in Azure Devops through the API and I am having trouble authenticating to my Azure devops organization. I have the request correct but I keep getting a

> 401 client error Unauthorized for URL

I have a PAT token to authenticate, I am just not sure how to add that into the request body to be able to authenticate to Azure Devops.  Below is the code that I am using to complete this. I have looked through all the documentation and I cannot find the syntax to complete this but I know a PAT token can be used to authenticate.

```
print("Would you like to Disable this repository in Azure Devops?")
disable = input("please select y/n: ")
if disable == 'y':
    pat = 'example'
    authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':' + pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'basic '+authorization
    }
    organization = "exmaple"
    disable_payload = '{"isDisabled": true }'
    disable_url = requests.patch(f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{i}?api-version=7.1-preview.1",
                                 data=disable_payload)
    disable_url.raise_for_status()
    print("Repo has been disabled")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone wondering, I was able to fix this issue.  Below is the final code output.  The data in the payload had to be changed to json.  the header had to be added in but needed to be headers. Finally, my i variable for some reason had a "\n" tacked onto the end of it which cause the URL to be faulty. I striped that from the variable and it worked!

```
                       # print("Would you like to Disable this repository in Azure Devops?")
                 disable = input("please select y/n: ")
                 if disable == 'y':
                     pat = 'example'
                     authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':' + pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
                     headers = {
                         'Authorization': 'basic '+authorization
                     }
                     organization = "example"
                     disable_payload = {"isDisabled": True }
                
                     i = i.strip("\n")
                     disable_url = requests.patch(f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{i}?api-version=7.1-preview.1",
                                                  json=disable_payload, headers=headers)
                     disable_url.raise_for_status()
                     print("Repo has been disabled")
```